# How can I build project, dependent on opencv 3.4.0 in RelWithDebInfo mode

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, debug-symbols

Here is my main cmake file:

```
project( reconstructor )                                    
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
set(CMAKE_SUPPRESS_REGENERATION true)
include(ExternalProject)
set(Boost_INCLUDE_DIR c:/boost_1_66_0)
set(Boost_LIBRARY_DIR C:/boost_1_66_0/lib64-msvc-14.0 )
SET("OpenCV_DIR" "C:/opencv-3.4.0/build")
find_package( OpenCV COMPONENTS core imgproc highgui aruco optflow REQUIRED )
add_subdirectory(prepare_folder)
add_subdirectory(draw_signal)
add_subdirectory(epipolar_reconstructor)
add_subdirectory(test_detection)
add_subdirectory(homography_matcher)
add_subdirectory(multiview)
add_subdirectory(filter_clouds)
add_subdirectory(filter_clouds_solid)
add_subdirectory(optical_flow)
add_subdirectory(prepare_splices)
add_subdirectory(skew_matcher)
add_subdirectory(triangle_matcher)
```

and my subproject file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin)
get_filename_component(CUR_PROJECT_NAME ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR} NAME)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS system filesystem REQUIRED)
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIR})            
FILE(GLOB cpps *.cpp)
FILE(GLOB commons ../common/*.c*)
add_executable( ${CUR_PROJECT_NAME}  ${cpps} ${commons})
set_target_properties(${CUR_PROJECT_NAME} PROPERTIES VS_DEBUGGER_WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin")
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})
target_link_libraries( ${CUR_PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```

But I can't build in RelWithDebInfo mode, in this case MSVC gives me these link errors:

```
1>epipolar_reconstructor.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::Rodrigues(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &)" (?Rodrigues@cv@@YAXAEBV_InputArray@1@AEBV_OutputArray@1@1@Z) referenced in function "struct std::pair<class cv::Mat,class cv::Mat> __cdecl calcR(struct View &,struct View &)" (?calcR@@YA?AU?$pair@VMat@cv@@V12@@std@@AEAUView@@0@Z)
1>triangulate.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::Rodrigues(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &)" (?Rodrigues@cv@@YAXAEBV_InputArray@1@AEBV_OutputArray@1@1@Z)
1>epipolar_reconstructor.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::stereoRectify(class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::Size_<int>,class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_InputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &,class cv::_OutputArray const &,int,double,class cv::Size_<int>,class cv::Rect_<int> *,class cv::Rect_<int> *)" (?stereoRectify@cv@@YAXAEBV_InputArray@1@000V?$Size_@H@1@00AEBV_OutputArray@1@2222HN1PEAV?$Rect_@H@1@3@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl handlePair(struct View &,struct View &,struct Folder &)" (?handlePair@@YAXAEAUView@@0AEAUFolder@@@Z)
```

(Debug/Release builds ok) How can I fix this?

Comment: See these related links: [10105](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/10105), [9656](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/9656). Either update to the latest OpenCV version or update your OpenCV version with the corresponding fixes.

Comment: Maybe your OpenCV version is not for your project, or you have wrote the wrong code. In `OpenCV 3.4`, I can't find the functions type either.

Comment: @Silencer It's [still in master](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/calib3d/src/calibration.cpp#L3213)

Comment: Tried to replace 3.4.1 with master branch, but I still get link error in RelWithDebInfo mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though I was unable to build in RelWithDebInfo mode, I've found a workaround. Enable debug info in your MSVC project and it will allow you to trace crash stack position:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I also had very often trouble using libraries with different build configurations. My solution is building every dependency with the same compiler flags as im building the project. Therefore I either add the project in cmake using the ExternalProject package or build the library multiple times with different configurations. With the second solution you will have to adjust your OpenCV_Dir respectively. However sometimes you just have to try to link the release/debug version when build in RelWithDebInfo mode and one will work.

Comment: plz provide some clear instructions, unfortunately I don't understand what to do.